# Rename wordpress.com tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Questions tagged [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) are off-topic, but people regularly miss-tag their questions believing it's a WordPress question therefore wordpress.com, not realising wordpress.com is a hosted service.

So, I suggest we rename it to [wordpress.com-premium-hosting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com-premium-hosting).

Comment: What is this tag needed for anyways, are there any questions with the tag that are not considered off topic?

Comment: we've tried deleting it in the past but it gets recreated, the problem with the tag is mostly that we can't give a mini-lecture prior to it being selected about how .org and .com are different, as the tag name itself is misleading without prior knowledge. I believe renaming it sidesteps that problem

Comment: I think that tag would suggest that it's okay to ask questions about premium support. Maybe clearly add an "off-topic" in tag's name? But then some people don't even know what off-topic means.

Comment: wordpress.com offers free hosting in addition to their paid alternatives. Do you suggest creating a wordpress.com-free-hosting tag as well?

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to that, unless you can think of a tag that covers both but still stops people tagging self hosted sites as wordpress.com unawares wordpress.com is a 3rd party entity ( albeit ones with very close/opaque ties to the open source project )

Comment: Maybe `wordpress.com-closed-box` or `wordpress.com-freemium-hosting`

Comment: If hypothetically both the free and premium `wordpress.com` tags would be considered off-topic anyways, why not just name it `wordpress.com-hosting` so there's only one tag? It's not like the free or premium would be handled differently than each other.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any harm in doing so. Hopefully users will think twice when adding the tag. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have renamed the tag to [wordpress.com-hosting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com-hosting).

I think it would be good to revisit this in a few months to see if this has had the desired effect of changing behaviour. If not I believe the dual tag approach suggested in the comments is a good avenue to explore for follow ups